# Docker Vertica's image fails to create database

Tags: docker, apple-m1, vertica

I have installed the docker image of vertica from https://hub.docker.com/r/vertica/vertica-ce . When I run a standalone docker container like shown in the site, the vertica's container fail to create the VMart database. I run the commands on a macbook air M1. Do you have some suggestions on how i can solve this problem?

This are the docker's logs:

```
VERTICA_DB_USER is "dbadmin"

Starting up

Moving config directory tree to persistent store

symlink /opt/vertica/config -> /data/vertica/config

Creating database

Info: no password specified, using none

Database with 1 or 2 nodes cannot be k-safe and it may lose data if it crashes

Distributing changes to cluster.

Creating database VMart

Starting bootstrap node v_vmart_node0001 (127.0.0.1)

Starting nodes:

v_vmart_node0001 (127.0.0.1)

Starting Vertica on all nodes. Please wait, databases with a large catalog may take a while to initialize.

Node Status: v_vmart_node0001: (DOWN)

Node Status: v_vmart_node0001: (DOWN)

Node Status: v_vmart_node0001: (DOWN)

Node Status: v_vmart_node0001: (DOWN)

Node Status: v_vmart_node0001: (DOWN)

Node Status: v_vmart_node0001: (DOWN)

Node Status: v_vmart_node0001: (DOWN)

Node Status: v_vmart_node0001: (DOWN)

Node Status: v_vmart_node0001: (DOWN)

Node Status: v_vmart_node0001: (DOWN)

ERROR: Database did not start cleanly on initiator node!

Stopping all nodes

Error: Database did not start cleanly on initiator node! Stopping all nodes


Loading VMart schema ...

Dropping old schema ...

Generating data ...

datadirectory = ./

numfiles = 1

seed = 20177

null = ''

timefile = Time_custom.txt

numfactsalesrows = 5000000

vsql: could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address

Is the server running on host "???" and accepting

TCP/IP connections on port 5433?

vsql: could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address

Is the server running on host "???" and accepting

TCP/IP connections on port 5433?

numfactorderrows = 300000

numprodkeys = 500

numstorekeys = 50

numpromokeys = 100

numvendkeys = 50

numcustkeys = 50000

numempkeys = 10000

numwarehousekeys = 100

numshippingkeys = 100

numonlinepagekeys = 1000

numcallcenterkeys = 200

numfactonlinesalesrows = 5000000

numinventoryfactrows = 300000

gen_load_script = false

years = 2003 to 2023

Data Generated successfully !

Creating schema ...

Loading files ...

Running ETL ...

Confirm successful load


Starting MC agent


Vertica is now running

vsql: could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address

Is the server running on host "???" and accepting

TCP/IP connections on port 5433?

vsql: could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address

Is the server running on host "???" and accepting

TCP/IP connections on port 5433?

vsql: could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address

Is the server running on host "???" and accepting

TCP/IP connections on port 5433?

vsql: could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address

Is the server running on host "???" and accepting

TCP/IP connections on port 5433?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$ docker run -p 5433:5433 -p 5444:5444 --name vertica_ce \
  --platform linux/amd64 \
  --env VERTICA_MEMDEBUG=2 \
  vertica/vertica-ce:11.1.0-0
```

...
as from here:https://forum.vertica.com/discussion/242629/support-apple-silicon-m1-for-docker-vertica-ce

Comment: Mine crashes all the same about once a day - but it's good for self training and demos ...